# Two nodes not joining Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I have an elasticsearch cluster in google cloud consisting of 3 nodes in which one is a master node. Now i don't know why my two nodes are not joining cluster only one node is in cluster right now. I used below command to start/stop/restart the other two nodes

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

when i ran above command for the two nodes there were no error shown but now when i try to use below command to retrieve my indexed data i got error on both of the nodes.

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/merchants/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    } 
}'                    
**curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused**
```

my **elasticsearch.yml** file is given below

```
  script.inline: on
  script.indexed: on
  script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
  script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: false



  # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
  #
  # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
  #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
  #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
  #
  # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
  # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
  #
  # Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
  # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
  #
  # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
  #
  # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
  #
  cluster.name: elasticsearch-cluster
  #
  # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
  #
  # Use a descriptive name for the node:
  #
  node.name: "elasticsearch-1-1-vm"
  #
  # Add custom attributes to the node:
  #
  # node.rack: r1
  #
  # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
  #
  # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
  #
  path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch/data
  #
  # Path to log files:
  #
  # path.logs: /path/to/logs
  #
  # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
  #
  # Lock the memory on startup:
  #
  # bootstrap.mlockall: true
  #
  # Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
  # available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
  #
  # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
  #
  # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
  #
  # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
  #
  network.host: 0.0.0.0
  #
  # Set a custom port for HTTP:
  #
  # http.port: 9200
  #
  # For more information, see the documentation at:
  # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
  #
  # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
  #
  # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
  # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
  #
  discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.128.0.5", "10.128.0.6", "10.128.0.4"]
  #
  # Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
  #
  # discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
  #
  # For more information, see the documentation at:
  # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
  #
  # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
  #
  # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
  #
  # gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
  #
  # For more information, see the documentation at:
  # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
  #
  # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
  #
  # Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
  #
  # node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
  #
  # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
  #
  # action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Can anyone please tell me what can be the best way to restart the elasticsearch cluster, i think my **sudo elasticsearch start** command is not working properly otherwise i must not have gotten connection refused error. Please if anyone know anything about ES cluster please help me i am stuck in this problem from past one week and havn't gotten anything useful till know.

Comment: What is an "arbitrary node"? And what version(s) are each node?

Comment: to reduce split brain problem in my cluster one is arbiter and other two are primary nodes. Each node is using ES 2.3 version.

Comment: So, one is a master-only node and the other two are data nodes?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: configure an initial list of master nodes in the cluster discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip.to.master.node"] (ONLY MASTER NODES, SO PUT ONE IP HERE)

Comment: If any ony of my node gets down then from other two any one can become master that's why i have written all three ips there, please tell me if i am doing anything wrong here ??